# What does 'default' varchar(255) in MySQL mean?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I came across this line in a MySQL script

```
 `other_validator` varchar(5000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `default` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `widget` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
```

What does this line signify?

```
`default` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
```

How can this be implemented in SQL Server?

Comment: It means you have a column named "default", which most RDBMS won't allow because it's a reserved word.

Comment: seems like just a field name to me, but using reserve keyword mistakenly.

Comment: http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-asarc/srg1100e/sqlref/@ebt-link;pt=3544;lang=fr?target=%25N%15_21932_START_RESTART_N%25

Comment: @Paul: most RDBMS will happily allow you to use a reserved word as an identifier or column name; you need to enclose them using appropriate characters. Some programmers go further and enclose just about every column name with appropriate delimiter.

Comment: Sure, you could all a field "null" as long as you surround it with "x" characters.  That doesn't make it a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing a column with a poor name. Try choosing a more descriptive name for the column. Other developers will be better off if you do.

You can use the square bracket delimiters for SQL Server.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    [defaultXyz] varchar(255)
)
```

SQL Server will let you give a column this name only using square brackets. Just don't do it. It's like giving a child a name of 'Kid'.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info. It's actually an extension which is using that column name. If I change it I would have to go inside the source code and see where it occurs and rename it. I think I will keep it as it is. I actually though it had special attributes that's why I was puzzled. Thanks again and to everyone else who contributed.

Answer (score 2):

It creates a field in your table called 'default' which is of the type VARCHAR with a length of up to 255 characters. It cannot be NULL and it defaults to an empty string, if no value is assigned to it in an `INSERT`.

Nothing special here... just plain ole SQL

Comment: Well, except for the fact that most other RDBMs won't allow you to use 'default' as a field name, and so this won't port to SQL-Server.

Comment: @Paul: It will port fine, as long as you replace the backquotes `\`default\`` with brackets: `[default]`

Comment: Which proves my point, that "default" is a bad name for a column.

Comment: @Paul: It certainly is and there is no argue about that. Just pointing that `default` is reserved in MySQL as well - not only other DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server uses brackets for reserved words.  e.g. [default]

But: don't do this, please.  Any time you forget to reference that column or table without the brackets, you will have really nasty errors.